# Disable Teaser in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

I'm attempting to disable the Teaser in Drupal **7**. All of the guides I've found deal with Drupal 6 or use unnamed plugins. I simply have a stock Drupal installation with no additional modules installed.

Where can I disable the Teaser function? Do I need a module? I really don't want to modify the theme or Drupal core as that's a bit, hackish.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove the Teaser display in Drupal 7:

1. Administer → Structure → Content types
2. click the "Manage display" link for your content type
3. drop down "Custom display settings"
4. uncheck "Teaser"
5. save the content type

Or did you mean disable the "Edit summary" link that drops down a textarea for a node summary? To do that:

1. Administer → Structure → Content types
2. click the "Manage fields" link for the content type
3. in the row for "Body", click the "edit" link
4. uncheck "Summary input"
5. save the content type

Comment: Which documentation did you look at? I'll dig around now and update what I can.

Answer (score 6):

If anybody is having problems with locating the "Manage Fields" link, make sure to enable the 'Fields UI' module.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was a vanilla installation I used. I could be wrong though

Comment: minimum D7 install doesn't enable Field UI